# Can't resize numpy image array although it has the right size

Tags: python, numpy

800*640*3 = 1440000 
So why is it giving me this error?

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1440000 into shape (800,640,3)

Comment: Recheck your math. 800*640*3 = 1536000.

Comment: hahah ups.. already late ;D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if it is right, you should use:

```
800*640*3 == 1440000
```

but the result will be "False".

In fact `800*640*3 = 1536000`.